# Reducing a Sorting Network

Tags: algorithm, sorting, graph-algorithm, sorting-network

A sorting network is an arrangement of 2 input comparators, which can sort an input sequence of n elements. 
For example, here's a sorting network for 9 element input:

[image]

Each of the vertical lines is a 2 input comparator, the input sequence enters on the left, and the sorted sequence appears on the right.

My question is: how to prove that if we remove the top or bottom line of any valid n input sorting network, we will end up with a valid sorting network for (n-1) inputs? What about removing any of the middle lines?

I have a feeling that this could be shown using a graph representation of a sorting network, but I can't find a suitable representation.

Comment: There's an easy way to reason about it: imagine that the element on the last line is always bigger than the others. In such a case, the comparisons with it will never move any element, but still sort the rest of the input. Since the comparisons with the last line never change anything, it means that removing them can indeed sort n - 1 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top or bottom line can indeed be removed. One way to prove this is using Knuth's 0-1 principle, which states that a sorting network is correct if and only if every sequence of zeros and ones is sorted correctly. Let `S` be a sorting network and let `S'` be `S` with the top line removed. Let `x` be a 0-1 input to `S'`. Pass `0x` to `S`. By induction, we can show that the values after `k` stages agree (except for the removed top line), since all of the gates involving the top line are no-ops. It follows that `S'` is a correct sorting network.

In general, we cannot remove a middle line. Consider, for example, the network

```
1 *   *
  |   |
2 * * *
    |
3   *
```

Comment: Can you please explain this statement: "By induction, we can show that the values after k stages agree"? If you pass zero input on the top line, you can assume that this value will stay on that line, and become the first output, so it can be safely removed. However, I don't see how this reasoning holds for passing 1 on the top line, how to show that after k stages, values from 1x and x will agree?

Comment: @MichaelSB We're proving that `S'` sorts correctly, so the universal quantifier is over all inputs `x` to `S'`. We're assuming that `S` sorts correctly, so we can choose the reference input to `S` (`0x`).